# jsp insert into database no utf-8

Tags: mysql, jsp, utf-8, sql-insert

I've got web-app (jsp) which is using database (mysql). I've put some data into database to test is it work to show in jsp what's in database There was issue with utf-8 characters (polish letters) but i fixed it by adding `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />` into glasfish-web.xml. But i still got problem with putting data into database from form. In database instead of polish character i got "?????". I've tried many thinks and nothing Dont reallu now where to look to fixit

Answer (score 1):

ok problem solved I'll put answer for other people having same problem
In jsp where i start my database connection for `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename` i changed it into

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

and now everything in database looks like it shoudl

Answer (score 0):

Problem you have faced is that java has escaped the UTF-8 character sequence.
you can use `StringEscapeUtils` provided by java in order to escape any characters which become `???` or anything else.
 try this :

`str = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str);`

From [java](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)